# How can I detect if the instance is const from a member function?

Tags: c++, constants

I would like to write a member function which detects if the instantiated object is const.

To give a simple example, we can consider the following class definition

```
class Foo{
  public:
    void constnessChecker(){
      bool isConst;
      // MORE CODE GOES HERE...
      if (isConst) {
        std::cout << "This instance is const! << std::endl;
      } else {
        std::cout << "This instance is not const! << std::endl;
      }
    }
};
```

and the following code

```
int main(){
  Foo foo1;
  Foo const foo2;
  foo1.constnessChecker();
  foo2.constnessChecker();
}
```

which should produce

```
This instance is not const!
This instance is const!
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Check `boost::is_const`, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_const.html

Comment: @ame: you cannot use that within the member function, can you?

Comment: Smells like a bad idea. What exactly is a `const instance` ? E.g. is a not-explicitly-const member const? I.e. `const struct { Foo foo; } bar;` - is `foo` a `const Foo` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Provide `const` and `non-const` overloads:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    void constnessChecker(){
      std::cout << "This instance is not const\n";
    }
    void constnessChecker() const {
      std::cout << "This instance is const\n";
    }

....
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Your answer implies that the compiler will first try to match the const version of the member function. Could you give me a reference for this?

Comment: @carlo No the compiler will try to match the non-const version only if the object is non-const. If there is no non-const version it will match the const one. Excuse the pun, but `const` is "constagious", so once added it propagates.

Comment: Note that calling `constnessChecker` from ctor or dtor will always report `not const`. In general, calling it from another member function will return whether _that member function_ is `const` or not.

Answer (score 0):

In the style of `boost::is_const` or `std::is_const`, you can also write up the following:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct is_const
{
  static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_const<const T*>
{
  static const bool value = true;
};

struct S
{
  void f() const
  {
    std::cout << is_const<decltype(this)>::value << std::endl;
  }

  void f()
  {
    std::cout << is_const<decltype(this)>::value << std::endl;
  }

  int m;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  const S& cs = S(); // note that choosing a const-ref is merely to force the compiler to choos S::f() const!
  cs.f ();  // prints 1

  S().f (); // prints 0

  return 0;
}
```

I haven't looked at the implementation of `std::is_const` but for some reason it returns false where the above `is_const` returns true.

Note: Obviously you need support for `decltype` and thus the above will only work for C++11 compliant compilers.

Comment: it's because `std::is_const` checks if the pointer is const, not the data to which the pointer points. with `std::is_const<decltype(*this)>` you'd get the correct behavior I believe