# How to make a pointer member data's constness vary with the parent instance's constness?

Tags: c++, constants, mutability

I have a class like this one:

```cpp
struct Example
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> pointer_member;
};
```

I'd like the type of `pointer_member` to be `std::unique_ptr<int const> const` when manipulating instances of `Example const`, and `std::unique_ptr<int>` when manipulating instances of `Example`.

The best solution I could think of so far involves templates, but it's really boilerplaty and not very usable (because the template arguments propagate to the code working with `Example`):

```cpp
template <bool is_const>
struct Example
{
    std::unique_ptr<std::conditional_t<is_const, int const, int>> pointer_member;
};
```

Also here, nothing prevents me from using `Example<false> const` instances and it's really annoying.

Any idea of how to achieve this in a better way?

Comment: Also the closest question I could find was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608550/how-can-i-detect-if-the-instance-is-const-from-a-member-function)

Comment: for some reason questions along this line come up rather frequently these days. Unless you need to, just don't overthink it. Actually propagating const with pointers is possible I think but not out of the box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encapsulation allows to control modifiable-ness (aka constness) of members:

```
#include <memory>
struct Example {
    const int& get() const {
        return *pointer_member;
    }
    int& get() {
        return *pointer_member;
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> pointer_member = std::make_unique<int>(42);
};


int main(){
    const Example ex1;
    const int& const_ref = ex1.get();
    Example ex2;
    ex2.get() = 123;
}
```

Comment: Any idea of how you'd transfer the ownership of `pointer_member` to another class?

Comment: @Louis-JacobLebel If you want to transfer ownership you should use a move constructor or move assignment operator.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes, its moved anyhow. I have to admit, I don't know if mine was doing more. Your suggestion to provide a move constructor is much more sound

Comment: Yeah, now that you mention it it's kinda obvious. Although, I'll have to change a lot of similar code and it's gonna be a pain with this approach (maybe should I have started with encapsulated members in the first place). Nevertheless it's definitely a valid way of doing it, thanks!

Comment: @Louis-JacobLebel there is too little context to help you with that pain. "maybe should I have started with encapsulated members in the first place" yes, const by default and private by default is the recipe for least pain on the long run.